# Is there anyway I can be notified on my phone when I receive bitcoin?

Tags: alert-system

I am not talking about getting notified on my desktop, but I am talking about my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Many wallet applications support mobile notifications, either through native notifications, SMS or email. CoinBase etc. populars should do this.

Furthermore if you know Bitcoin addresses some third party services like block.io can be used to send notifications when a certain address receives a transaction.